# continue prior message without newline

Tags: echo-area, message

I'm trying to...

```
(message "%s" (concat "Attempting to delete " (nth ix flist) "... "))
(delete-file (nth ix flist))
(message "OK.")
```

And I don't want a newline at the end of "...".  I want "OK." to be on the same line.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Like `Auto saving...` => `Auto saving...done`

Answer (score 2):

```lisp
(let ((msg (concat "Attempting to delete " (nth ix flist) "... ")))
  (let (message-log-max)
    (message "%s" msg))
  (delete-file (nth ix flist))
  (message "%s" (concat msg "OK.")))
```

This is the standard method because the code that comes with Emacs distribution implements what you want the same way.

---

BTW, it's a good convention to write this way: `(message "%s" YOUR-STRING)`.